# Which one is the best performance when you access all the various views of cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In iOS development ,we always met the various view of cell?I know there’re two methods -come true this mode…..
sometimes people always give their cells views a tag ,but I know it requires a bit of casting.If combining with one improperly tagged view,you will get a runtime error as a result…..I know Tags are a useful way to reduce hard-coded dependencies and support more dynamic and flexible solutions. Rather than storing a pointer to a view, you could locate it using its tag. Tags are also a more persistent way of referring to views.
eg:

```
let bookCoverLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILable
label.text = icon.title.
```

The other way is to create a UITableView subclass.In it you can provide outlet directly hook into the interface of cell,thus you can access all your various views…

one:Create Subclass

```
class coverTableViewCell:UITableViewCell
```

Second:Set the class of cell in identity
Three:Connect subviews to outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var coverImageView:UIImageView!
```

That’s the simple progress to custom the cell you need,most developers always do it….But here I wanna ask one question -how is the performance   ……….Perhaps it’s one stupid question…..I just wanna think about it more……...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no difference in performance while you use tag or custom class because ultimately you will end up making a object for that particular view or component and access it through that object. Tag or outlet points to the component thats it.

But, i don't prefer using tags because i hate remembering numbers!!! also when iOS 7 was introduced, tableview cell came with a container view which was not present in iOS 6 thus at that time it was a hell of time to those developers who used tag because view with tag was not giving proper view or component as output. While using custom class at that time was boon :D.

When you use custom class, you just have to bind the outlets and just access the outlets. And you don't have to remember the numbers :D.

For me it's always convenient to use custom class. So according to me there is not much difference in both the ways but i prefer custom class.

This may be a stupid reply but this is my point of view :)

Hope this may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah tag is always ignored to fulfill in the related position.It's not a good method to do.This method searches the current view and all of its subviews for the specified view.If the there're more tags here ,the performance will be worse than We think,so nobody use it again....Deprecate it completely -only for reference..